# Change menu order of core post-type in UI?

Tags: admin-menu, dashboard, user-interface

I'd like to move **Posts** from it's position (5) in the Dashboard Menu.

I tried to re-register it with only the menu order, but it no longer displays at all.

```
function reorder_core_post_types() {
    register_post_type( 'post', ['menu_order'=>10] );
}

add_action( 'init', 'reorder_core_post_types' );
```

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1):

This article is a little old now, but it helped me on a project once:

https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/customizing-your-wordpress-admin--wp-24941

Hope it helps.